# Is there a faster way to delete a directory using Cygwin command line without deleting every single file/sub-directory?

Tags: cygwin

I'm trying to delete a directory so I can clone it from github again, since it got messed up. But there are just way too many files/sub-directories to remove them individually. Is there a faster way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want the `rm` command.

```
rm -rf my_messed_up_repo
```

look at `rm --help` for more info.